# Image not loading in ejs nodejs even though linked correctly (nodejs, cloudinary, express, ejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image, ejs, cloudinary

I am unable to view my image in the browser even though  it loaded successfully (I inspected the code).

I am using mongodb, expressjs and ejs.

The image link was saved in database but actual image was saved in cloudinary. I have no idea what is going wrong. Please help.

[View the image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIb3V.png) 
All the development is local

I also tried to load an image from public directory which worked successfully.

I googled but did not find any solution.

Here is the code in the ejs template:

```html
 <div class="col-md-4 ">
                    <% if(campground.images.length)  {%>
                        <!-- <img src="/hello.png " alt=" " srcset=" "> -->
                        <img class="img-fluid " alt="camp image " src="<%=campground.images[0].url%>" />
                        <% }else{ %>
                            <div>no image</div>
                            <% } %>
                </div>
```

Comment: image url may not have the image extension specified. you can add the extension next to ejs ending of url `src="<%= url %>.jpg"`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do not post code as image. Copy code and paste here as  code; there is a very nice `formatting aid for code`. And do provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you.